# Recording video from webcam with C# Accord .Net

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, aforge, accord.net

I'm trying to record video from my webcam. For that i'm using Aforge and Accord.

I'm building it with windows forms.

The video source and video writer are:

```
private AForge.Video.DirectShow.VideoCaptureDevice videoCaptureDevice = null;
private Accord.Video.FFMPEG.VideoFileWriter _writer;
```

I'm calling **Open** on the writer like this :

```
var w = (int)Math.Round((double)pic.Width, 0);
var h = (int)Math.Round((double)pic.Height, 0);
_writer.Open(dialog.FileName, w, h,25,VideoCodec.MPEG4);
```

In the **NewFrame** event of the **videoCaptureDevice** i'm doing:

```
    Bitmap b = (Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone();
    if (recording)
    {
        if (firstFrameTime.HasValue)
        {
            _writer.WriteVideoFrame(b, DateTime.Now - firstFrameTime.Value);
        }
        else
        {
            _writer.WriteVideoFrame(b);
            firstFrameTime = DateTime.Now;
        }

     }
```

I have tried also

```
_writer.WriteVideoFrame((Bitmap)eventArgs.Frame.Clone())
```

and

```
_writer.WriteVideoFrame(eventArgs.Frame)
```

but keep on getting exception : **Parameter is not valid**

Any ideas what i'm doing wrong here?

tnx

Answer (score 0):

Which parameter is not valid?  This is the only way I got it to work:

```
writer.Open(
  <filename>.mp4,
  FrameWidth, FrameHeight,
  new Rational(Playback),
  FFMPEG.VideoCodec.MPEG4
);
```

NB: filename must have an .mp4 extension and VideoCodec must be MPEG4.

```
// Save Bitmap Frame; use one or other
writer.WriteVideoFrame(Frame); 
writer.WriteVideoFrame(Frame, TimeSpan.FromTicks(Now.Ticks-FirstFrame));
```

NB: if latter, use timespan, not ticks.